# JScrollPane loses scroll position when focus lost

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm working on a legacy swing application.

This app has a customised `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane`.

The problem I have is that when the application loses focus (e.g. Alt-Tabs to another app), the scrollbar and caret position return to the top.  What I want to happen is that when focus is lost, the caret position and scroll value remain unchanged.

I currently have a focus listener which stores the caret position and scroll bar value when focus is lost and sets it again when focus is gained.  Which works.  However it looks a little shonky because the scroll bar still jumps to the top when focus is lost and moves back when focus is gained.

Is there a way to suppress the focus event, or otherwise stop the scroll bar moving when focus is lost?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet someone build a feature to scroll up and show the beginning of the Text everytime the content of the `JTextArea` changes via `setText()` or `append()`.

**And** that the there is another (`Window`, `Focus`, `Document` or `PropertyChange`) `Listener` which (maybe saves and) refreshes the content of the `JTextArea` when the `JFrame` is deactivated to not loose any useredits.

This two features don't go well together...

Comment: This was indeed the problem.  In the one of the subclasses of `JTextArea` the `setText()` method included a call to `setCaretPosition(0)`.  This was being triggered by a `FocusListener` which was listening for updates to propogate changes through to the workflow model.

Answer (score 2):

Given it does not occur in this simpler code, my suggestion would be:- change whatever it is in the code that is *causing the problem in the first place.*

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ScrollPosition {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    ScrollPosition() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(4, 20);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
        String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            ta.append("Blah blah.. " + i + eol);
        }
        ta.setCaretPosition(0);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScrollPosition o = new ScrollPosition();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Scroll Position");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, with all respect, giving an answer of "fix the thing thats broken" (paraphrasing) isn't much help when the code base is many millions of lines of code.  But I do appreciate the code snippet, as it saves me writing something similar to swap my companies proprietry classes into.  So thanks :)